# Grouping elements of one column of matrix according to values of another column into cell array

Tags: matlab, matrix, grouping

I've been trying to come up with a smart way of doing this for a while. Given a matrix (or cell) with the following structure:

```
A = [-1  1 
     -1  2 
      1  3 
      3  5
      2  3 
      2  4 
      2  7  
      4  5 
      5  6 
      6  7 
      7 -2 ]
```

(Note that the above matrix/cell is unsorted in both columns and contains negative numbers).

How could one group it by the unique values of a particular column. E.g. the desired output for grouping by the second column would be something like:

```
B{1} = [-1]
B{2} = [-1]
B{3} = [1,2]
B{4} = [2]
B{5} = [3,4]
B{6} = [5]
B{7} = [2,6]
B{-2} = [7]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you say *matrix (or cell)* - this is quite a difference!

Comment: and this `B{-2} = [7]` is invalid matlab syntax.

Comment: in above code you show that indx as negative number but as matlab syntax you cant use less or equal 0 as a indx .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [**`accumarray`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
[~,~,subs] = unique(A(:,2));
values  = accumarray(subs,A(:,1),[],@(x) {x});
ofGroup = accumarray(subs,A(:,2),[],@(x) {x(1)});

out = [ofGroup values]
```

---

```
out = 

    [-2]    [         7]
    [ 1]    [        -1]
    [ 2]    [        -1]
    [ 3]    [2x1 double]
    [ 4]    [         2]
    [ 5]    [2x1 double]
    [ 6]    [         5]
    [ 7]    [2x1 double]
```

---

If you ***REALLY*** insist on your order proposed, you could do the following, but I don't think that should be necessary.

```
% positives
pos = A( A(:,2) >= 0 , :);

[~,~,subs] = unique(pos(:,2));
posvalues  = accumarray(subs,pos(:,1),[],@(x) {x});
posofGroup = accumarray(subs,pos(:,2),[],@(x) {x(1)});

% negatives
neg = A( A(:,2) < 0 , :);

[~,~,subs] = unique(neg(:,2));
negvalues  = flipud( accumarray(subs,neg(:,1),[],@(x) {x}) );
negofGroup = flipud( accumarray(subs,neg(:,2),[],@(x) {x(1)}) );

out = [posofGroup posvalues; negofGroup negvalues ]
```

---

```
out = 

    [ 1]    [        -1]
    [ 2]    [        -1]
    [ 3]    [2x1 double]
    [ 4]    [         2]
    [ 5]    [2x1 double]
    [ 6]    [         5]
    [ 7]    [2x1 double]
    [-2]    [         7]
```

Comment: Maybe use `'stable'`?

Comment: @Divakar I though about it, but I'm not sure, if it is what the OP wants, but I will include it. Because in his output its kind of sorted.

Comment: Even I am not sure, double checking with the expected output could be better I guess.

Comment: @Divakar, he wants the sorted version, but the negative ones at the end

Comment: tehwaywewalk & @Divakar This is great! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
[group, ~, subs] = unique(A(:,2))
B = accumarray(subs, A(:,1), [], @(x){x'})
```

Results in

```
B= 

    [  7]
    [ -1]
    [ -1]
    [2,1]
    [  2]
    [4,3]
    [  5]
    [2,6]
```

and `group` matches the index of `B` to the number of the group it represents

Also if you are attached to your ordering then you can do this:

```
[group, ~, subs] = unique(A(end:-1:1,2), 'stable');
B = flipud(accumarray(subs, A(end:-1:1,1), [], @(x){x'}));
group = flipud(group);

B = 

    [        -1]
    [        -1]
    [1x2 double]
    [         2]
    [1x2 double]
    [         5]
    [1x2 double]
    [         7]

group =

     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
    -2
```